# Add clickable handle to material ui SwipeableDrawer

Tags: css, material-ui

Any idea if its possible to add a clickable handle to a material ui SwipeableDrawer? Similar to google maps here:

[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/San+Francisco,+California/Antarctica/@-0.8718683,-148.2370674,3z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x80859a6d00690021:0x4a501367f076adff!2m2!1d-122.4194155!2d37.7749295!1m5!1m1!1s0xa4b9967b3390754b:0x6e52be1f740f2075!2m2!1d-0.071389!2d-75.250973!3e2)

button.css

```
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: -50px;
width: 50px;
height: 100px;
z-index: 10000; // This was intended to get above both of the other elements
```

SlideableDrawer

```
top: 0;
flex: 1 0 auto;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
z-index: 1200;
outline: none;
position: fixed;
overflow-y: auto;
flex-direction: column;
```

backdrop.css

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: -1;
position: fixed;
touch-action: none;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

[image]

Ideally this handle would be sitting at side of the page when the drawer wasn't active.

sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-einstein-jzluw

The drawer doesn't function for some reason, but my question (I think) is more related to the css anyway.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in Codesandbox and update your question with what you are looking for exactly?

Comment: @daydreamer Sandbox added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To make this button fully visible, you need to override the overflow-y of MuiDrawer-paper.
You can do that using MuiTheme:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiDrawer: {
      paper: {
        overflowY: 'visible',
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And also wrap your component with ThemeProvider:

```
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     {your component...}
  </ThemeProvider>
```

You can refer to my implementation at CodeSandbox (i haven't tried to make the drawer function properly, just designed the button): [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-solomon-wc6us?fontsize=14)